# Build WHERE clause in SQL dynamically and execute without hard parsing

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

Build WHERE clause in SQL dynamically and execute without hard parsing

I want to build SQL dynamically, adding/changing/removing WHERE conditions until record has been found.
Adding/Changing/Removing WHERE conditions is based on priority set by business rules.

To better describe the problem statement, here are my 2 tables (sample key columns) with structure

Table 1: -->   This table hold claim related information for each claim submitted.

```
CLAIM_DOCUMENT   
--------------
(
HDR_SID NUMBER,
PRVDR_NPI   NUMBER,
INV_TYPE    VARCHAR2(4),
SPLTY       VARCHAR2(100),
PRCDR_CODE  VARCHAR2(100),
MDFR_CODE   VARCHAR2(10),
DIAG_CODE   VARCHAR2(100) )
```

Table 2: --> This is configuration table that holds provider rate.

```
PROVIDER_RATE  
-------------
( PRVDR_SID     NUMBER,
PRVDR_NPI       NUMBER,
SPLTY           VARCHAR2(100),
SUB_SPLTY       VARCHAR2(100),
PRCDR_CODE      VARCHAR2(100),
MDFR_CODE   VARCHAR2(10) 
RATE_VALUE      NUMBER(20,6)
RATE_TYPE       VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

The goal is to determine applicable RATE_VALUE from PROVIDER_RATE table.
To determine provider rate we match the attributes (i.e. PRVDR_NPI, PRCDR_CODE, MDFR_CODE) submitted on claim with that to PROVIDER_RATE to find RATE_VALUE.

It’s possible that all attributes on claim may not match with PROVIDER_RATE, so we ADD/CHANGE/REMOVE “WHERE” conditions until we find RATE_VALUE from PROVIDER_RATE table.

For e.g.  in 1st pass, the business rule says match all possible values, so I write SQL statement as below:

```
SELECT RATE_VALUE, RATE_TYPE into v_rate_value, v_rate_type 
FROM CLAIM_DOCUMENT cd, PROVIDER_RATE pr
WHERE cd.hdr_sid = p_hdr_sid      -- p_hdr_sid is passed as parameter to procedure for 1 claim
AND cd.PRVDR_NPI = pr.PRVDR_NPI    -- PRVDR_NPI is key column to match between 2 tables
----all optional where clause to form here based on busienss rules priority --
AND cd.PRCDR_CODE = pr.PRCDR_CODE          -- optional WHERE clause 1
AND cd.MDFR_CODE = pr.MDFR_CODE          -- optional WHERE clause 2
AND cd.SPLTY = pr.SPLTY               -- optional WHERE clause 3

--IF rate value is NOT found using all WHERE clause above, the next rule priority 
--is to REMOVE SPLTY and check
    IF v_rate_value IS NULL THEN
        SELECT RATE_VALUE, RATE_TYPE into v_rate_value, v_rate_type 
        FROM CLAIM_DOCUMENT cd, PROVIDER_RATE pr
        WHERE cd.hdr_sid = p_hdr_sid      -- p_hdr_sid is passed as parameter to procedure for 1 claim
        AND cd.PRVDR_NPI = pr.PRVDR_NPI    -- PRVDR_NPI is key column to match between 2 tables
        ----all optional where clause to form here based on busienss rules priority --
        AND cd.PRCDR_CODE = pr.PRCDR_CODE          -- optional WHERE clause 1
        AND cd.MDFR_CODE = pr.MDFR_CODE          -- optional WHERE clause 2
    END IF;
--IF rate value is NOT found using WHERE clause above, 
--the next rule priority is to REMOVE MDFR_CODE and check
        IF v_rate_value IS NULL THEN
            SELECT RATE_VALUE, RATE_TYPE into v_rate_value, v_rate_type 
            FROM CLAIM_DOCUMENT cd, PROVIDER_RATE pr
            WHERE cd.hdr_sid = p_hdr_sid      -- p_hdr_sid is passed as parameter to procedure for 1 claim
            AND cd.PRVDR_NPI = pr.PRVDR_NPI    -- PRVDR_NPI is key column to match between 2 tables
            ----all optional where clause to form here based on busienss rules priority --
            AND cd.PRCDR_CODE = pr.PRCDR_CODE          -- optional WHERE clause 1
        END IF;
```

My question: 
Is there a way to build WHERE clauses DYNAMICALLY by reading the business rules configured in a table and more importantly execute the 
DYNAMIC formed SQL statement WITHOUT hard parsing?

Comment: Sure, just read the business rules, put them in a `variable varchar2(100)` and `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE variable`

Comment: How many variations of the queries will there be?  If there will only be 3 then hard-parsing doesn't really matter.

Comment: I don't want to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE because this procedure is most frequently used and I am sure this will create performance issues.  There could be many variations, so I was thinking to make it more configurable and dynamic but not at the expense of performance

Comment: Just one hint: using `SELECT ... INTO ...` raises exception if query returns zero or more than one row so this exact query syntax will not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be acceptable to conditionally turn conditions on/off like this:

```
AND (cd.PRCDR_CODE = pr.PRCDR_CODE OR l_prcdr_code_flag='off')  -- optional WHERE clause 1
AND (cd.MDFR_CODE = pr.MDFR_CODE OR l_mdfr_code_flag='off')  -- optional WHERE clause 2
AND (cd.SPLTY = pr.SPLTY OR l_splty_flag='off')  -- optional WHERE clause 3
```

All you have to do in the rest of your code is to handle "flags", ie. set all the `l_*_flags` variables to `'on'` on start, and then just turn them off (set them to `'off'`) as you go.
This way you don't change SQL, so hard parsing is not necessary.
It would be also a good idea to create a cursor variable for your query to avoid duplicating code.

Comment: First, thanks GoranM.  Not sure if I get it right, so I want to ask this scenario.  How flag will help if I don't have to consider MDFR_CODE and SPLTY at all per business requirements for e.g. could you please provide me query with flags assuming I have to execute only the following:                                                                                             {  AND (cd.PRCDR_CODE = pr.PRCDR_CODE OR l_prcdr_code_flag='off')  -- optional WHERE clause 1}

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT RATE_VALUE, RATE_TYPE, 
       CASE
         WHEN
           cd.PRCDR_CODE = pr.PRCDR_CODE          -- optional WHERE clause 1
           AND cd.MDFR_CODE = pr.MDFR_CODE          -- optional WHERE clause 2
           AND cd.SPLTY = pr.SPLTY               -- optional WHERE clause 3
         THEN 1
         WHEN
           cd.PRCDR_CODE = pr.PRCDR_CODE          -- optional WHERE clause 1
           AND cd.MDFR_CODE = pr.MDFR_CODE          -- optional WHERE clause 2
         THEN 2
         WHEN
           cd.PRCDR_CODE = pr.PRCDR_CODE          -- optional WHERE clause 1
         THEN 3
       END matching_factor
  FROM CLAIM_DOCUMENT cd, PROVIDER_RATE pr
 WHERE cd.hdr_sid = p_hdr_sid      -- p_hdr_sid is passed as parameter to procedure for 1 claim
   AND cd.PRVDR_NPI = pr.PRVDR_NPI
 ORDER BY 3;
```

This way you'll catch all the records that satisfy join condition (`cd.PRVDR_NPI = pr.PRVDR_NPI`) and `matching_factor` will tell you which additional conditions are satisfied too (`1` => all 3 optional clauses are satisfied, `3` => only PRCDR_CODE clause is satisfied).
Order the result set according to this matching factor and the first row should be the best match.
Did I get it right this time?

Comment: Thanks GoranM for your support.  Your solution certainly looks better.  Your solution works well when we have to know all permutations possible during design and implementation.  I was kind of more interested to check what if a new change request comes in which said check for PRVDR_NPI and SPLY and this should be at highest priority.  Can we accommodate this change request without changing code?  Let me know if you need more details.  Thanks again GoranM